# Visual Studio 2019 step over (F10) working as Continue (F5) while debugging release build in Docker Linux container

Tags: docker, visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files, release-builds

While creating an ASP.NET 5.0 project which is being deployed into an Alpine Linux container (with corresponding pdb files generated), I've noticed that I can't use step over or step into when my breakpoint is hit. VS is able to attach to the container's process and all specified breakpoints are hit  (ie, VS stops at the right places and the watch and local windows shows the expected values).

However, if I hit F10 or F11, the ide will jump to the next breakpoint (or run till the end if there are no more breakpoints) instead of moving to the next line or stepping into the method that is being called.

Has anyone else faced this issue? Is there a solution for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, deleting .suo + .vs folder seems to have done it and now f10 works flawlessly...